Finding the coordinates of the quadrilateral, derived from two intersecting line segements whose coordinates are given.
I want the coordinates of the quadrilateral formed from two intersection line segments, where the opposite sides of the quadrilateral should be parallel to one of the intersecting line segments. For better understanding, I have attached an image.

In the image how do I find the coordinates of points $\text{A, B, C, D}$?
Is there any approach for getting the coordinates of the quadrilateral formed? I have tried one method, but it didn't work, so finding other ways to get the coordinates of the quadrilateral formed.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Please provide the method you tried, so that we can avoid doing the same mistake as you have done

@Gwen, first i found the intersection point of two line segments, after getting intersection point( I ), i planned on finding the fourth point of the quadrilateral S,I,P,A where A is the fourth point,  similarly for other points, with it's respective small quadrilateral and finally get the fourth point, but this method didn't seem to work

More desirable method(using vectors)
The point of intersection is $\bigg(\frac{11}{3},\frac{11}{3}\bigg)$. We take this point as the new origin of our graph. This changes the coordinates of $S,P,Q,R$ such that their new coordinates are $\bigg(x-\frac {11}{3},y-\frac{11}{3}\bigg)$.This gives us four nice vectors$$\vec{p}=\frac 73 \hat{i}+\frac 73 \hat{j} \\
\vec{q}= \frac 13 \hat{i}-\frac{2}{3} \hat{j}\\
\vec{r}=-\frac 53 \hat{i}-\frac 53 \hat{j}\\
\vec{s}=-\frac 23 \hat{i}+\frac 43 \hat{j}$$
Now we use the parallelogram law, to state that $$\vec{a}=\vec{p}+\vec{s}\\=\frac 73 \hat{i}+\frac 73 \hat{j} -\frac 23 \hat{i} +\frac 43 \hat{j}=\frac 53 \hat{i}+\frac {22}{3} \hat{j}$$
Thus $A$ has new coordinates $\bigg(\frac 53, \frac{22}{3}\bigg)$. To find the original coordinates, add $\frac {11}{3}$ to both coordinates to get $A\equiv \bigg(\frac{16}{3},\frac{22}{3}\bigg)$.
Similarly use $\vec{b}=\vec{p}+\vec{q},\vec{c}=\vec{q}+\vec{r},\vec{d}=\vec{r}+\vec{s}$ to find $B,C,D$, and thus the entire $\text{parallelogram}$
Using theory from straight lines
$AB||CD||SQ$ and $BC||PR||AD$, thus they have same slopes. Slope of $SQ=-2$, slope of $PR=1$.
Use the equation $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1),m=\text{slope}$$
To find equations of $AB,BC,CD,DA$ and then solve each pair simultaneously to get $A,B,C,D$

thanks for your solution i have checked it, the quadrilateral is not  in the way which i showed in the image, the quadrilateral is small

@BasavarajKittali check the edited post, particularly the hyperlink

thanks a lot, i made a mistake in calculation. I got the correct coordinates.
Thanks for your help Gwen.
